# QueryFailedError: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm, nest

I am trying to create a `manyToMany` relationship between User table and Broker table and want to add some additional properties to it.

My idea is to add some additional properties into UserBroker manyToMany relationship, but facing this error, please help me to find what exactly I am doing wrong ?

Here is my code:

```ts
export default class AbstractEntity<T> {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    constructor(entity: Partial<T>) {
        Object.assign(this, entity);
    }
}

@Entity({
    name: "user",
})
export class User extends AbstractEntity<User> {
    @ManyToMany(() => Broker, broker => broker.users, { cascade: true })
    @JoinTable({
        name: "user_broker",
        joinColumn: { name: "user_id", referencedColumnName: "id" },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: "broker_name",
            referencedColumnName: "name",
        },
    })
    brokers: Broker[];

    @OneToMany(() => UserBroker, userBroker => userBroker.user)
    userBrokers: UserBroker[];
}

@Entity({
    name: "broker",
})
export class Broker {
    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: "enum",
        enum: IntegratedBroker,
        default: IntegratedBroker.b1,
    })
    name: IntegratedBroker;

    @OneToMany(() => UserBroker, userBroker => userBroker.broker)
    userBrokers: UserBroker[];

    @ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.brokers)
    users: User[];
}

@Entity({
    name: "user_broker",
})
export class UserBroker {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.userBrokers)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "user_id", referencedColumnName: "id" })
    user: User;

    @ManyToOne(() => Broker, broker => broker.userBrokers)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "broker_name", referencedColumnName: "name" })
    broker: Broker;

    @Column()
    additionalProperty: string;
}

export enum IntegratedBroker {
    b1 = "b1",
    b2 = "b2",
}
```

Though I have defined `id` in UserBroker column and set it as a PK.

Here is the error log:

```
[Nest] 17724  - 01/08/2024, 8:24:01 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key  
QueryFailedError: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
    at Query.onResult (**\driver\mysql\MysqlQueryRunner.ts:246:33)
    at Query.execute (**\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:36:14)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (**\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:478:34)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (**\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (**\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (**\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
```

Comment: Thing to notice in this situation is that the Broker table is holding Enum data, which is primary key.
I am not sure if anyhow this is causing the issue or not.